# Why do I get this warnings under Cython?

Tags: cython

I try to reproduce some examples on the Cython tutorial to learn Cython:

http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/external.html

I think the two following warnings are not related. Therefore two qestions:

(1)

Using this as input to

> python setup.py build_ext --inplace -c mingw32

```
from libc.math cimport sin

cdef extern from "math.h":
    cdef double sin(double x)


cpdef double f(double x):
    return sin(x*x)

cpdef test(double x):
    return f(x)
```

I get:

```
D:\python\cython>python setup.py build_ext --inplace -c mingw32
Compiling primes.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing primes.pyx
warning: primes.pyx:4:19: Function signature does not match previous declaration
running build_ext
building 'primes' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include -c primes.c -o build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\primes.o
writing build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\primes.def
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\primes.o build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\primes.def -LC:\Python34\libs -LC:\Python34\PCbuild -lpython34 -lmsvcr100 -o D:\python\cython\primes.pyd

D:\python\cython>
```

Why is the warning "Function signature does not match previous declaration" ?

(2)

When I declare

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    cpdef double sin(double x)
```

I get the additional warning

```
warning: primes.pyx:4:20: Function 'sin' previously declared as 'cpdef'
```

However, it is given exactly in the same way as example in the chapter "External declarations" of the linked page. In a python module where the module is imported, sin is not known under the package. Where is the problem?

The description in the tutorial is:

```
Note that you can easily export an external C function from your Cython module by declaring it as cpdef. This generates a Python wrapper for it and adds it to the module dict.
```

Comment: _"I think the two following warnings are not related. Therefore two qestions:"_ One question per question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the different parts of the tutorial show *different* manners to call C functions.

For some functions for which a Cython `.pxd` header is provided, you can use `from libc.math import sin`. For all libraries, you can use the lengthier method of `.h` header and re-declaration.

You cannot mix the two however, as it creates two definitions of the same function even though they are identical.

Comment: I understand. Is the second issue related to that ?

Comment: Very probably :-) `Function 'sin' previously declared as 'cpdef'` is also about multiply defined names. You should try anyway for yourself. Just an additional note: if you want to iteratively test Cython programming, you can do so using Jupyter notebooks http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html?highlight=ipython#using-the-ipython-notebook